# php: wordwrap text file contents to fit it in letter-size print page ( each line to Pixel width)

Tags: php, printing

I want to print simple text file (no style, formatting ) ,such that it fits in letter-size page and any overflow should be wrap to next line etc.

```
 wordwrap()
```

php wordwrap function is doing what needed , but I am not sure how much character at maximum that fit on single line of letter-size page.

I hope this is not silly question . Do I need to look other way e.g px /font-size / max page size in pixels etc .

thanks in advance for any kind of help :)

**Note:** printing will be done from desktop application like notepad , wordpad or whatever text editing application available

Comment: PHP doesn't know how you're going to print the file, so it's impossible to estimate how much space each character will take. But that is essential to find out how many characters a line can have

Comment: I take it you DO NOT mean when a user selects Print from a webpage in a browser .. because if so then you can constrain the width of the page with a special @print css rule.

Comment: @Cups no not from webpage . The file will be downloaded , and then printed from e.g wordpad or notepad. I just want to add new line (as the wordwrap() does ) if line length goes beyond certain size .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: printing will be done from desktop application like notepad , wordpad or whatever text editing application available

You won't be able to predict at what size the text is going to be printed out on client side, so this will be completely impossible to do in PHP. You'll have to rely on the client doing the line breaks.

If you need full control over the printed result on that level, consider generating a PDF file.

Comment: thanks, I have pdf generation already setup for printing.Text output is another export option. But sometime text lines go too long so client wants to trim to a letter-size. Can't we guess no of characters for a letter size with default setting e.g font-size 10 etc ..